# Using custom fonts in FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, custom-font

I've been using the following method to use Custom font in my RecyclerView. 
This is the `onCreateViewHolder` method of my `RecyclerViewAdapter`

```
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, parent, false);
    fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)v);
   //..........
}
```

I was wondering if I could use the same thing in `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` as I don't have access to that class and it's `onCreateViewHolder` method.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Read this : https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html

Comment: @mujjuraja how does that answer the question?